# Flexslider prev/next navigation appears below images in wordpress

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, wordpress, flexslider

I followed this article to enable flexsliderhttps://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/adding-a-responsive-jquery-slider-to-your-wordpress-theme--wp-27914

I found they use font-awesome rather than image for the navigation and got it sorted out correctly.

However the prev/ next navigation are not showing up at their locations. I believe this has something to do with css.

Can someone guide me on how to fix this please?

[image]

I got the navigation appearing side by side after changing the 
`left:10px` and `right:10px`  to `left:1px` and `right:1px` for these class.

```
.flexslider:hover .flex-direction-nav .flex-prev {
  opacity: 0.7;
  left: 1px;
}

.flexslider:hover .flex-direction-nav .flex-next {
  opacity: 0.7;
  right: 1px;
}
```

Why could this kind of issue happen and what could the fix in css?

The image slider html

```
 <div class="flexslider">
                <ul class="slides">

                    <?php
                    // The Loop
                    while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); ?>
                        <li>

                        <?php // Check if there's a Slide URL given and if so let's a link to it
                        if ( get_post_meta( get_the_id(), 'wptuts_slideurl', true) != '' ) { ?>
                            <a href="<?php echo esc_url( get_post_meta( get_the_id(), 'wptuts_slideurl', true) ); ?>">
                        <?php }

                        // The Slide's Image
                        echo the_post_thumbnail();

                        // Close off the Slide's Link if there is one
                        if ( get_post_meta( get_the_id(), 'wptuts_slideurl', true) != '' ) { ?>
                            </a>
                        <?php } ?>

                        </li>
                    <?php endwhile; ?>

                </ul><!-- .slides -->
            </div><!-- .flexslider -->
```

Answer (score 0):

There are too much missing informations for givin a precise answer, as there are only css for the two navigation buttons, but I guess it could have something to do with a parent `position:` (or sizing properties) property or something like that.